# How can I return all the rows in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS table within a radius of Xkm provided by a longitude and latitude value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to have a go at learning about PostgreSQL and in particular, it's PostGIS extension and the benefits with regards to geographic spatial features it provides. I've loaded a PostgreSQL DB with a table that contains 30,000 records of latitude, longitude and a price value (for houses) and I want to start querying the DB to return all the rows that would be in a radius of Xkm of a particular latitude and longitude.

I've hit a brick wall as to how I might run this type of query as I've found the documentation to be quite limited online and I've found no similar attempts at this method of querying online.

Some methods I've tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM house_prices
WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_MakePoint(53.3348279,-6.269547099999954)) <= radius_mi * 
1609.34;

This prompts the following error:
ERROR:  function st_dwithin(geometry) does not exist
```

Another attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM house_prices ST_DWithin( 53.3348279,  -6.269547099999954,   5); <-- A latitude value, longitude value and 5 miles radius

This prompts the following error:
ERROR:   syntax error at or near "53.3348279"
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction/ know of some documentation I could look at?

** Edit **
 Structure and set up of database and table in pgAdmin4

[image: Screenshot - Cant embed as reputation still too low]

Comment: Are you sure your database has the GIS extensions? How did you add them? ST_DWithin takes two geometries, so you're going to need that ST_MakePoint, but the second argument should be the point from your table, and the third argument your distance. if I understand the documentation that would be something like `WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_MakePoint(long,lat), house_prices.location, radius_mi * 1609.34)` depending on what you named your geometry column

Comment: I downloaded postgreSQL and also included the postGIS extension. I know this as there is a PostGIS option under the extensions tab of my database. I don't have a  geometry column which may be the issue? I have four columns an id, latitude, longitude, and price column. Have I set this up incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query has an invalid number of parameters. The function **[ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)** expects at least two geometries and the srid distance, 
 and optionally a Boolean parameter indicating the usage of a spheroid (see [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)).

The second query is missing a `WHERE` clause and has the same problem as the first query.

Example from [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

```
SELECT s.gid, s.school_name
    FROM schools s
        LEFT JOIN hospitals h ON ST_DWithin(s.the_geom, h.the_geom, 3000)
    WHERE h.gid IS NULL;
```

Perhaps something like this would be what you want to achieve:

```
SELECT *
FROM house_prices h
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(53.3348,-6.2695),h.geom,h.radius_mi * 1609.34)
```

Also pay attention to the order of the coordinates pair (*x,y* or *y,x*), otherwise you might easily land on the sea with these coordinates ;-)

**EDIT**： Taking into account that there is no geometry on the table, so the points are stored in two different columns, longitude and latitude:

```
SELECT *
FROM house_prices
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),ST_MakePoint(53.3348,-6.2695),1609.34)
```

Comment: I ran that query in my query tool in PostgreSQL and the h.geom part prompted an error. Another answer to this question suggested something about a geometry column. Do I have to enter a column into my table for geom or provide a value for it?

Comment: Yes, you'll need a point column on house_prices if you want to find distance between it and any other point, or check that that distance is within a limit.

Comment: as lotyrin said, this `h.geom` is the geometry column you just mentioned. You need a geometry column in the table `house_prices` in order to be able to calculate the distance :-)

Comment: maybe we can assist you better if we know how your table and record look like.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply and apologies for the late reply I've updated the question with a screenshot of what I'm talking about. Cheera

Comment: Where does the column `radius_mi` come from?

Comment: I just added a new query to my answer.

Comment: Your answer is almost correct but you will run into an issue with the unit given in the third parameter. The SRS chosen is WGS84, that's why the third parameter will be in degrees, not in meters.
You should use geography type to use meters instead :

`SELECT *
FROM house_prices
WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude)::geography,ST_MakePoint(53.3348,-6.2695)::geography,1609.34)`

See this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/76968/69447 for more infos.

Comment: It's pretty hard to know which CRS he's using, since you're storing the coordinates as numbers - WGS84 is the most common though. I sincerely recommend to store this values in one single column using the geometry type (where you can set the CRS). Thanks for the observation :-)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Jim! Starting to understand PostgreSQL and PostGIS a little better. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! By now you can accept the answer as solved, so that other users can find it more easily.